# how to write multiple management commands in one file? django

Tags: python, django, command

I have been reading how to write a django management command by reading [this](http://janetriley.net/2014/11/quick-how-to-custom-django-management-commands.html).

I did also read the django documentation but I am wondering if it's possible to write few commands to run using only one file?

instead of writing a few different files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.  If I'm reading the source correctly commands are discovered from CLI by looking for modules:

[https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/**init**.py#L26](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/__init__.py#L26)

Which collects using:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules

Comment: Well I read the docs and it clearly states that it discovers commands from each of the module which defines a class Command. Agrees with dm completely.

Comment: thx thx, just thought there might be a chance for alternatives

Comment: Check this out - I think you can rework this to meet our needs. Really cool script. http://masnun.com/2015/09/29/python-django-running-multiple-commands-in-subprocesses.html

Answer (score 1):

You can write multiple commands in one file. Follow below steps

1. Create **management/**init**.py** folder under your app root directory
2. Under management directory create **commands/**init**.py** folder
3. Create mycommand.py file under commands directory
4. Write below codes in mycommand.py file

```js
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from subprocess import Popen
from sys import stdout, stdin, stderr
import time
import os
import signal


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Run all commands'
    commands = [
        'python manage.py schedule',
        'python manage.py runserver'

    ]

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        proc_list = []

        for command in self.commands:
            print("$ " + command)
            proc = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=stdin,
                         stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
            proc_list.append(proc)

        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(10)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            for proc in proc_list:
                os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

5. Change you cmd directory to yourProject root dir
6. Run: `python manage.py mycommand`

This [link](http://masnun.com/2015/09/29/python-django-running-multiple-commands-in-subprocesses.html#comment-379596) helped me.